# How to map two arrays of objects, concatenate them, and add an index efficiently

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two different arrays of objects that need to be mapped individually to key:value pairs defined by me. When mapping, each of the objects should be assigned a sequential index. Then, I need to take each of the mapped arrays and concatenate them.

This is what I've tried so far. It works, but I think there might be a more efficient or clean way to do it:

```
const mapPosts = () => {
        let index = 0

        const mappedPostsA = postsA.map(post => {
          index++
          return {
            id: index,
            provider: 'Wordpress',
            post_id: postA.id,
            title: postA.title,
            body: postA.body_html
          }
        })

        const mappedPostsB = postsB.map(post => {
          index++
          return {
            id: index,
            provider: 'Blogspot',
            post_id: postB.id,
            title: postB.title,
            body: postB.description
          }
        })

        const mappedPosts = [...mappedPostsA, ...mappedPostsB])
      }
```

Comment: Is that a typo? where is `postA` and `postB` defined? why do you want the same properties on each object?

Comment: I think you meant to use `post` and `product` inside those map functions instead of `postA` and `postB`.

Comment: @dandavis it's not a typo. They're defined earlier, but their definitions don't really matter. And if you look closely, they're not the same properties. Each object comes from a different provider. For example, postA's body_html maps to body, while postB's description maps to body.

Comment: @Ace the typo was on the second map - already corrected it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just offset the index by the length of `postsA`, as you know `postsB` will always be right after it.

```
const mapPosts = (postsA, postsB) => {
    return [
        ...postsA.map((post, index) => ({
            id: index,
            provider: 'Wordpress',
            post_id: post.id,
            title: post.title,
            body: post.body_html
        }))
        ...postsB.map((product, index) => ({
            id: index + postsA.length,
            provider: 'Blogspot',
            post_id: product.id,
            title: product.title,
            body: product.description
        }))
    ];
};
```

I used the spread syntax since you used it in your original question, you could use something like `mappedA.concat(mappedB)` instead, but this is mostly a matter of preference.

Comment: I think it is also a good idea to pass postsA and postsB as parameters, so that the function does not have side effects, but rather acts according to the data it receives.

Comment: Agreed. The question was not about that and seemed to get them from an outer context but it is probably a good idea to change it to parameter values.

Comment: @NicoDiz that's a great idea indeed; thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about efficiency, and if you have a lot of objects, you might want to consider using a Map instead of a plain object. Maps are specifically tailored to efficiently handle key-value pairs.  You might get a slight performance boost, or at least slightly more readable code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 0):

To remove code duplication, I'd probably do

```
const mappedPostsA = postsA.map(post => ({post, provider: 'Wordpress', body: post.body_html}));
const mappedPostsB = postsB.map(post => ({post, provider: 'Blogspot', body: post.description}));

const mappedPosts = [].concat(mappedPostsA, mappedPostsB).map(({post, provider, body}, index) => ({
    id: index,
    provider,
    post_id: post.id,
    title: post.title,
    body,
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a good idea indeed, but my objects have more different fields than similar ones. I should've specified that.